# How can I use chmod on remote files?

Tags: c++, unix, sftp, chmod

I have an SFTP server set up at home which uses FreeBSD 11.0, and I am writing a program that would also do simple permission changes. How would I change file permissions on the remote host?

I have tried looking for libraries all over that were both user-friendly and could support this, but to no avail do they match my criteria. I decided to try and write my own support, but I don't know how I would accomplish this.

Pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```cpp
void setFlags (short flags) {
    // Set remote file's permissions based on flags (example flag: 744)
    FILE *rfile = fopen ("/remote/file/path.txt", 'w');
    chmodRemote (rfile, flags);
    fclose (rfile);
}
```

Edit: I don't want to use `system ("foo");` for this.

Comment: You have to either mount the server locally or run the program on the remote server not locally.

Comment: Did you try passing in the network location `\\\\remove\file\path`?

Comment: What do you use to transfer files to/from or list files on the SFTP server? Which libraries did you try? Please [edit] your question and add the information there instead of answering in comments.

Comment: `FTP` is not part of the standard C++ library and what you need is to issue the `FTP` command `CHMOD` - so, either write your own `FTP` class or find a library that implements the `FTP` protocol.

Comment: why not `ssh user@remotehost_or_ip "cd /path/to/dir; chmod -x files_to_fix*"`? Of course you'll have to set up access for `ssh` on your remotehost, but that is the simplest way. Good luck.

Comment: If using `system()` commands is ok, I'd go for `ftp`, `tftp` or similar since that doesn't require any additional setup or letting remote users, that should only have FTP access, in via ssh. James: take a look at `libcurl` it's a `C` lib but has FTP [examples](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html) that you can modify.

Comment: Please explain why `libssh` doesn't fit your bill. Example: [`sftp_chmod`](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__sftp.html#gaeb224e6feefedb94e7f1325cca50ecc0). And of course, you could just call `sftp(1)` in batch mode via `system(3)`. Also, clarify if/that you're **really using SFTP**, not FTPS, FTP, CIFS or other thing. Looking at the comments, it really is necessary ;-)

Comment: Or `libssh2`: [libssh2_sftp_stat_ex](https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_sftp_stat_ex.html).

Comment: try this: https://www.example-code.com/cpp/ftp_chmod.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution after all this time.

1. Connect to the SFTP site using `sys/socket.h` under its set port (default 22, the SSH port). The encryption technique you choose (Symmetric Encryption, Asymmetric Encryption, and Hashing) will have to be set up by you however if you choose to do this process by hand, as this is how SSH makes decryption possible on the destination device, all of which (and packet format) is explained [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253). You may also want to find how you can retrieve data over the session.
2. Send a packet with all the metadata needed since this is a shell session (a la "FTP over SSH"). This is also how other commands can be sent.

Do note that if you want backwards compatibility with FTP, you will need to refer to [a raw FTP commands list](https://nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm) since the old version does not use shell packets; you will need the `SITE` command (followed by the server's command and arguments) for that, no surrounding fluff, just raw data.